# Random generating numbers on a given ratio

Tags: python, random

I need to generate numbers on a positive given interval (a,b) distributed following an exponential distribution. Using the **Inverse CDF Method**, I made a generator of a number exponentialy distributed. But, of course, this number is a positive number and I want it to be on the given interval. What should I do to only generate on the interval?

The code to generate a number exponentially distributed using the inverse cdf method is, in 
 Python

```
u = random.uniform(0,1)
return (-1/L)*math.log(u)
```

where L is a given positive parameter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could discard numbers that aren't in that interval, although your function then has a variable and potentially infinite run time.

Comment: Yes, thats why I want to generate this on the interval, but I have no idea of how can I do this

Comment: If you can figure out an ``L`` such that the return from your inverse CDF will always be ``0-1`` you can just use that as the percentage along your interval you are.

Comment: It is not possible, since it will always generate numbers with an exponential distribution with parameter L. It will be on the interval (0,infinite)

Comment: yeah I just thought about that. If your values coming out of your distribution aren't bounded, I don't think you have any choice but rejection sampling. Unless you can figure out a ``u`` bound that would limit the output (since ``return -> infinity`` as ``u->0``)

Comment: yes, but this will not generate numbers exponentially distributed or I will need to make any transformartion that generates a number exponentially distributed and it will be on (0, infinite). I think there is no efficient solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of an outcome *x* would normally be *L* exp(*-Lx*).  However, when we are restricted to [*a,b*], the probability of *x* in [*a,b*] is scaled up by 1/the fraction of the CDF that occurs between *a* and *b*: integral from *a* to *b*(*L* exp(*-Lt*)*dt*) = -(exp(*-Lb*) - exp(*-La*)).

Therefore, the pdf at x is

*L* exp(*-Lx*))/(exp(*-La*) - exp(*-Lb*),

giving a cdf at x of

integral from *a* to *x*[ *L* exp(*-Lt*)/(exp(*-La*) - exp(*-Lb*))*dt*]

= [-exp(*-Lx*) + exp(*-La*)]/[exp(*-La*) - exp(*-Lb*)] = *u*

Now invert:

exp(*-Lx*) = exp(*-La*) - *u*[exp(*-La*) - exp(*-Lb*)]

*-Lx* = *-La* + log( 1 - *u*[1 - exp(*-Lb*)/exp(*-La*)])

*x* = *a* + (-1/*L*) log( 1 - *u*[1 - exp(*-Lb*)/exp(*-La*)])

giving code:

```
u = random.uniform(0,1)
return a + (-1/L)*math.log( 1 - u*(1 - math.exp(-L*b)/math.exp(-L*a)) )
```

be aware: for large L or a, `math.exp(-L*a)` will round to 0, leading to `ZeroDivisionError`.

Comment: see http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~xmeng/Course/CS6337/Note/master/node50.html for steps in derivation.

Comment: but, in this case,does the sample generated still distributed exponential(L)? I don't see why this is true

Comment: In this case, I think should I use L exp(-Lx))/(exp(-La) - exp(-Lb) as function, since I need it for a simulation

Comment: yes, you should use L exp(-Lx)/(exp(-La) - exp(-Lb)) as your probability function.  The CDF is calculated using the PDF L exp(-Lx)/(exp(-La) - exp(-Lb)), so that is how your numbers will be distributed.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can use this to solve my problem, since the random number generator does not generates a sample distributed following my original distribution

Comment: what is your original distribution?

Comment: the exponential distribution, I meant. By the way, I think you just made a mistake at the step -Lx = -La + log( 1 - u[1 - exp(-Lb)/exp(-La)]), since the logarithm of the sum is not the sum of logarithms.

Comment: i distributed exp(-La) out to get exp(-La)(1 - u[1 - exp(-Lb)/exp(-La)]) and then took the log of that.  the logarithm of a product is the sum of the logarithms.

Comment: Lexp(-Lx) is the exponential distribution, no?  Then you need to normalize by (exp(-La) - exp(-Lb)) so that the integral of the pdf over [a,b] equals 1.

Comment: Yes, I understood, but the problem ask me to use a generator for this exponential, not for the new function. I need to see if I can use it, your soluction looks pretty good to me